# Eclipse fails to resolve a method from a vector made of class pointers (C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I have a class that looks like this:

```
enum DATA_TYPE {bla, bla2};
class Mem_Data
{
private:
    DATA_TYPE m_eType;
    uint32    m_nLineAddr;
    uint32    m_nPhysAddr;
    uint32    m_nSize;
    int       m_nIndex;
public:
    Mem_Data(DATA_TYPE eType, uint32 nLineAddr,uint64 nPhysAddr,uint64 m_nSize, int nIndex = 0);
    DATA_TYPE GetType();
    int GetIndex();
    uint32 GetLineAddr();
    uint32 GetPhysAddr();
};
```

I then create a vector that is made from pointers of this class:

```
Vector<Mem_Data *> m_dataVec;
m_dataVec.push_back(new MemData());
m_dataVec.push_back(new MemData());
m_dataVec.push_back(new MemData());
```

(Of course I put data to match my constructor but this is just an example)

But when I try to access a function from the class inside the vector Eclipse fails to resolve it.

```
m_dataVec.front()->GetType()
```

The above fails to resolve.
However this seems to work:

```
Mem_Data *p = m_dataVec.front();
p->GetType();
```

This does resolve but it seems inelegant as it forces me to add another variable and not access the class instance directly.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: From the answer you created, I'm going to say that the failure is because you're trying to call a non const member function from a class pointer inside a const vector. Get a non const vector, and you'll be able to call the member function you want to

Comment: This is cve:
'class CVE
{
private:

public:
 Vector<Mem_Data *> m_dataVec;
 uint32 m_nCBDone;

 int EnableInterrupts(); 

};'

Comment: As you can see, there is no mention of const in it.

Answer (score 1):

[vector.begin()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) returns an iterator.

In order to get access to the data stored in the vector, or more specifically, to the data the iterator points to, you need to *dereference the iterator*.

you do this with either `operator*()` or `operator->()`.

In your example, you would do this as follows:

```
auto iterator = m_dataVec.begin(); // get iterator from vector
Mem_Data *p = *iterator;           // dereference iterator to get Mem_Data pointer
```

You can dereference `begin()` in one line using `*`:

```
*m_dataVec.begin() // this is a Mem_Data pointer
```

You can then get access to the data the pointer is pointing as using either `*` or `->`:

```
(*m_dataVec.begin())->GetType();
```

Note here the parens around `(*m_dataVec.begin())` are necessary because of operator precedence.

Another way to do the same is double-dereference, which would give you access to `Mem_Data&`:

```
**m_dataVec.begin().GetType(); // double deref - 1st the iterator, then the pointer
```

Comment: Or simply `m_dataVec.front()->GetType()`. The `front` function returns reference to the first stored object, not an iterator.

Comment: Sorry, got confused when I made the post, I did use m_dataVec.front() not  m_dataVec.begin().

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using:

```
((Mem_Data*)cve.m_dataVec[0])->GetLineAddr()
```

It seems that the vector implementation kept trying to use the consts [] operator instead of the normal [] operator, and this solved it.

Comment: This is a bad idea. You're casting away constness. You should rather find out why`cve` is const, and fix your design so that you have mutable access.

Comment: Also, as a general rule of thumb, you should always look at your code as being the source of the bug, not the std library. 99.99% of the time, the std library is correct, and it is your code that's wrong. Here, saying "for some reason the impl kept trying to use the const [] operator...", well that's by design, and I'll bet `cve` is const

Comment: This is what confuses me, cve is just a class that holds a vector, there is nothing const about it. I don't understand why its trying to sue the const operator

Comment: Update your question to show where you get `cve` from, and then maybe we can see where the problem is. At the moment the compiler is telling you that `cve` is const, which is why you can only access `operator[]() const`. Also, rather than say "eclipse fails to resolve", post the actual error message you get, as that will also help us help you